# Permutation problem of trading dolls

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are $n$ girls, numbered $1,2,...,n$. In the morning, each girl has a doll: Girl number $k$ has doll number $k$. Then, each pair of girls (in some order) traded their dolls. 
My question is: When is it possible that at the end of the day, each girl will have the doll she started with? 
 Of course that because of permutation pairity arguments, since there were $n \choose 2$ trades, we must have $n \choose 2$ even. 
 Is it enough? Whenever we have $n \choose 2$ even, is it always possible to have any pair of girls trading their dolls such that at the end girl $i$ has doll number $i$?

Comment: $(12)(34)(13)(24)(14)(23)=()$ so it works for $n=4$.

Comment: Yes. See Theorem 4 of Ron Evans, Lihua Huang & Tuan Nguyen, Keeler's Theorem and Products of Distinct Transpositions, Monthly 121, February 2014, 136-144. This is behind a paywall, but I think the article is also freely available on arXiv. There's a construction based on repeated use of the identity, $(ab)=(ac)(ab)(bc)$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you!

Comment: The futurama theorem! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Prisoner_of_Benda

Answer (score 1):

Consider any solution for $4k$ girls, such as Gerry Myerson's when $k=1$.

For $1\le i \le k$, replace each transposition $(ab)$ where $a=2i-1$ and $b=2i$ by
$(af)(ae)(ad)(ac)(ab)(bc)(bd)(be)(bf)$,where $c,d,e,f$ are four new girls and multiply by Gerry Myerson's solution for $c,d,e,f$.

This gives a solution for $4k+4$ girls. Note that a solution for $4k+1$ girls is obtained simply by replacing each transposition $(ab)$ where $a=2i-1$ and $b=2i$ by
$(ac)(ab)(bc)$.

Comment: The conclusion being that you can do any $n\ge4$ congruent to zero or one modulo $4$, and those are precisely the values of $n$ for which $n\choose2$ is even.

Comment: That's exactly it.